I wanted to write a code to count the number of fields in Access, but I encountered a problem
When I write the code to count the fields, it gives me this error

you omitted an operand or operator, you entered an invalid character or comma, or you entered text without surrounding it in quotation marks.

I am sure that I have written the name of the field and table correctly and I do not know what is the cause of this error.
My field contains both numeric values ​​and text values and I used this code but it gives an error :
=dcount("contractnumber","tblproject")


Try the simpler syntax:
=DCount("*","tblproject")

or you have semicolon as the list separator:
=DCount("*";"tblproject")


Thank you for your help, I tried it but it still gives the same error as before

Perhaps you need a semicolon ...

It still gives an error.
There is no other code to count the number of fields?

Fields? You mean records? That's what DCount counts.

Are you trying to count the rows in a table (using dcount()), or are you trying to get the number of columns in a table regardless of the number of rows in the table?
Finding out the number of columns in a table is not often required, but you can.
So, to find the number of rows in a table, then, say in the debug/immediate window, you can type in this:
? "number of rows in tblHotelsA = " & dcount("*","tblHotels")
number of rows in tblHotelsA = 317


? "number of columns in tblHotels = " & currentdb.TableDefs("tblHotels").Fields.Count
number of columns in tblHotels = 27

So, here is a screen shot of the above in the immediate window (hit ctrl-g to bring up the immediate window) looks like this:

So, counting the number of columns in a table is different then counting the number of rows in that table.
